# How to run an animation onload event

Tags: openlayers-3

I follow [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html) to create a "fly to" effect.

In the example, you have to "click" a button to run the effect, i would like to run the effect when page is loaded.

I tried to "listen" the body tag with the "load" event, like this :

```
var flyTo = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
flyTo.addEventListener('load', function() {
```

It does not work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your question in this thread: [Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

In addition if you use jQuery you can also ensure your code is executed once the page is loaded with [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

`$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});`